# What's the correct way to initailise empty states in react with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm quite new to react and was wondering what was the correct way to initialise empty state variables in react. Currently I have a form in typescript which has several fields to fill. Most of those fields are dropdowns and i've initialised some static data as an array of objects something like this.

```
export const options = [
    {
        id : 0,
        name : "Setting 1"
    },
    {
        id : 1,
        name : "Setting 2"
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        name : "Setting 3"
    }

];
```

So I'm able to display these options it in the dropdown of the form and everything is working as expected. Problem comes when i try and initialise the  state that I'm using to check up on the updates on this field.

```
const [myForm, setMyForm] = React.useState({
        dropdown : options[0],
        dropdown1 : options1[0]
    });
```

So for me in the `myForm` object that I've cerated to keep track of the state, I get the first option by default as selected as I've specified. I cannot initialise it to `null` as typescript requires a type for any declaration. What's the best practice to initially have the value as an empty object, and set it later when the user checks the option from the dropdown. Because if i set it to an empty object like `{}` in the `options` i cannot access the `id` and the `name` fields in the code. Can anyone tell me what's the correct way to do it

Comment: Given there is an initial render step there anyway, what default values of `id` and `name` does it expect?

Comment: @zerkms i just want it to be empty, should i add an extra object in the `options` array which has `id` as -1 and name as "-1" or is there a way to have the state set to null and use the object fields(`id` and `name`) or do i need to add an extra object?

Comment: What does "empty" exactly mean? If you read an `id` property - what value do you expect there *by default*?

Comment: Empty as in, nothing is selected, let's say for explanations sake `id = -1` and `name = "-1"` in the dropdown

Comment: Any react hook is generic. So you can use generic to describe state type. Like `useState<{} | null>(null);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`useState` can take a type. This is good for when Typescript can't infer the type from the type of the initial value. This is often the case with any `null` default value. You need to tell typescript what the value could be when it's not `null`.

For example:

```
const [name, setName] = useState<string | null>(null)

// name is of type: string | null
if (name != null) console.log(name.toUpperCase())
```

I don't entirely follow your code here, but I think you may want to set your state's type like this, with a value as an optional. This means it's allowed to be missing or undefined.

```
interface State {
  dropdown: FormField
  dropdown1: FormField
}

interface FormField {
  id: number
  name: string
  value?: string
}
```

And then use that type:

```
const [myForm, setMyForm] = React.useState<State>({
  dropdown : options[0],
  dropdown1 : options1[0]
});

myForm.dropdown.name // allowed, and type is: string | undefined
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i was looking for, the correct way to do it.